# Data lost on Restart of Eclipse

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

Every time i **restart my System**,and run my app on **Eclipse**,the **database is initially empty**.
It does not retain my previous data.
I create my own **DB(internal)**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean on a virtual device:

[image]

Check from AVD->start, if you have the tap "Wipe user data" checked.

Comment: Thanx!
But there isn't any such option.

Comment: There isn't any? When you start AVD manager, choose the right virtual device and then click start? Maybe you have an older environment then.

Comment: currently i am using 3 emulators. but i run this app in this specific one.it works well through the day,but when i run the app next day, all my data is gone.

Comment: i am using "Juno" version of Eclipse. does it has to do anything with it.

Comment: ya it was there. Thanx for ur Help